# Elasticsearch match query with terms array doesn't return partial match hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 queries. The outcome is such that

- Query A with exact text match returns hits
- Query A with partial text match returns hits
- Query B with exact text match returns hits
- Query B with partial text ***does not return hits***

Why does Query B with partial text not return hits? My expectation is that `{"match": {"_all": "PARTIAL_OR_COMPLETE_TEXT_HERE"}` would match in all 4 cases. The only difference I can tell is that the non-working query uses `"terms": []` whereas the working query only uses `"term": ""`

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Query A

```
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "_all": "RSTCPLS-1F56E8B836"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "merchant_id": 10012
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "sb_status": "open"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "has_unfulfilled_quantity": "true"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "sb_payment_status": "all"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "ordered_at": {
              "gte": "1992-04-01T17:01:39Z",
              "lte": "2017-05-01T10:01:39-07:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "is_archived": "false"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Query B

```
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "_all": "test123"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "merchant_id": 10012
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "sb_status": [
              "open,",
              "completed"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "last_shipment_state": [
              "created",
              "submitted",
              "processing"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "sb_payment_status": "all"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "ordered_at": {
              "gte": "1992-04-01T17:03:12Z",
              "lte": "2017-05-01T10:03:12-07:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "is_archived": "false"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE

Here is a more direct query that targets my nested field.  I get hits for this query, but when I remove one character from the `nested_items.sku`, I get no hits.

```
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "nested_items",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "nested_items.sku": "RSTCPLS-1F56E8B836"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my mapping

```
{"orders_development_20170403084520375"=>
  {"mappings"=>
    {"order"=>
      {"_all"=>{"analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"},
       "dynamic_templates"=>
        [{"string_template"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"index"=>"analyzed", "type"=>"text"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024, "include_in_all"=>true, "type"=>"keyword"}}}],
       "properties"=>
        {"billing"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "billing_contact"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "billing_email"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "channel_id"=>{"type"=>"long"},
         "created_at"=>{"type"=>"date"},
         "display_ref"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "has_unfulfilled_quantity"=>{"type"=>"boolean"},
         "is_archived"=>{"type"=>"boolean"},
         "item_names"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "last_shipment_state"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text"}}, "include_in_all"=>true, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "merchant_id"=>{"type"=>"long"},
         "nested_items"=>
          {"type"=>"nested",
           "properties"=>
            {"extended_total_in_cents"=>{"type"=>"long"},
             "name"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text"}}, "include_in_all"=>true, "ignore_above"=>1024},
             "quantity"=>{"type"=>"long"},
             "quantity_fulfilled"=>{"type"=>"long"},
             "sku"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text"}}, "include_in_all"=>true, "ignore_above"=>1024}}},
         "order_ref"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "ordered_at"=>{"type"=>"date"},
         "sb_order_seq"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text"}}, "include_in_all"=>true, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "sb_payment_status"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text"}}, "include_in_all"=>true, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "sb_status"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text"}}, "include_in_all"=>true, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "shipping_contact"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "shipping_email"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "skus"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "status"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text"}}, "include_in_all"=>true, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "total_in_cents"=>{"type"=>"long"},
         "updated_at"=>{"type"=>"date"},
         "warehouse_ids"=>{"type"=>"long"}}},
     "_default_"=>
      {"_all"=>{"analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"},
       "dynamic_templates"=>
        [{"string_template"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"index"=>"analyzed", "type"=>"text"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024, "include_in_all"=>true, "type"=>"keyword"}}}],
       "properties"=>
        {"billing"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "billing_contact"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "billing_email"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "display_ref"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "item_names"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "order_ref"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "shipping_contact"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "shipping_email"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024},
         "skus"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_middle"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_middle_index"}}, "ignore_above"=>1024}}}}}}
```

Comment: Did you make a typo #line19: `"open,",` (comma before quote and comma after quote)? Also just a silly question - are you sure you have documents which satisfy such a criteria as *query B* ?

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks for finding the comma. Turns out it didn't affect the outcome. I've narrowed it down to the search term itself.  "12345" and "singleword" will yield no partial matches in the nested field. However, "multiple words" and "ABC-123-DEF-456" will find hits on partial text matches in the nested fields.  I'm now looking into my mapping and how to ensure my nested fields are analyzed correctly.

Comment: So, I think it's worth to share your index mapping :) And sorry for silly question - I don't see you are using nested fields here - could you please elaborate where do you use it in above-mentioned queries?

Comment: @PaulVasilev I've updated my question above.

Answer (score 1):

Well I solved my problem. It was simpler than I thought. In setting up my nested mapping, I needed to add `"index": "not_analyzed"`

```
order: {
  properties: {
    nested_items: {
      type: "nested",
      properties: {
        "sku" => {type: "string", index: "not_analyzed"},
        "name" => {type: "string", index: "not_analyzed"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps others who encounter similar problems.